# {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Tags: c#, format, type-conversion

Basically, I am trying to multiply price by quantity but it's not working.
I get this error:

> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

The data was stored in cookies which I want to drive and multiply i.

```
new DataColumn("quantity"), new DataColumn("Price") //and its basically stored in a cookie
int tot;
tot = tot + (Convert.ToInt32(a[4].ToString()) * Convert.ToInt32(a[5].ToString()));
```

Bellow is the screenshot of the debugging results
[image]

Comment: What is the value of a[4] amd a[5]?

Comment: What are the values of a[4] and a[5]. Let me guess, nothing which can be convert to an int ;)

Comment: put debugger point and check value of a[4] and a[5] that causes issue at run time

Comment: if you extract data from outer source, i'd recommend you use Int32.TryParse method instead. It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed. do this prior to any calculation. also, in your case, adding to 'tot' is redundant , its zero. always.

Comment: This question exists hundreds of times on the site already, and the answer is always the same: your string does not contain a number. Read [ask] and share you research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of Conver.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) tells us that the `FormatException` is thrown when:

> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

So basically your string can only have this format `+` or `-` followed by digits which are not allowed to be separated by a space or anything else but a digit.

`ToInt32` is even so fair as it allows you to have a preceding or trailing space ;)

Edit:

The format is meant like this:

```
string input_pos = "+42"; // or
string input_neg = "-42";
Convert.ToInt32(input_pos) + Convert.ToInt32(input_neg);    
                           ^
                           |
                        //This has nothing to do with the format!
```

the format refers to the string that you pass as parameter into the `ToInt32()` method, and not how you calculate the resulting numbers!

Apparently you have a floating number in your array `3.49` this cannot be converted to an `int` but it can be converted into a `double`:

```
double tot = (Convert.ToDouble(a[4]) * Convert.ToDouble(a[5]));
```

the `ToString()` call is not necessary

Comment: any way of multiplication sign please

Comment: @khans the problem is **not** the asterisk between the `Convert.ToInt32()` calls, it's in the string you pass to that method.

Comment: `? I don't really understand you. But nothing else than + or - is allowed. it is like in math, the sign determines whether the number is positive or negative

Comment: @khans Pleace put this line into your application `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", a));` and post the output from the output window

Comment: @khans as you can see the '.' is not allowed. You would need to convert it to ' double'. I edit my answer in a second

Comment: but its not working with + sign either

Comment: @khans the format refers to the string that you pass as parameter into the `ToInt32()` method, and not how you calculate the resulting numbers! See my edit

Comment: Thanks it worked now cheers buddy

Comment: @khans you are welcome. Next time, check the format first  then decide how to convert ;)